# Jquery toggleClass on inline SVG

Tags: jquery, svg

I've got a layout with an inline SVG (an archaeological drawing of a site's floor plant) with some explanatory text in a sidebar and I would like to change some of the attributes of the groups I've made inside the SVG by toggling the classes of the different groups. 
I'm trying to use JQuery's `toggleClass()` but it is not working. I would like to bind the changes on the class to some click events on `<span>` elements on the  sidebar.
Does Jquery not work with SVG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  jQuery is designed to work with HTML.  SVG elements are in the SVG namespace and the jQuery functions generally don't work on them.

You can modify an SVG element's `class` using `setAttribute()`:

```
mysvgelement.setAttribute("class", someclass);
```

Or use one of the various JS support libraries for SVG manipulation.

Comment: I found a couple of libraries to achieve the funcionalities I was needing. [Lunar.js](https://github.com/toddmotto/lunar) and [pan and zoom](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom). Thanks for the answer.